# Java: what exactly does a headless install mean?

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm installing Java and Tomcat on a headless server. The client doesn't have Java and just sees a webpage.

Should I install openjdk-17, or openjdk-17-headless?

Comment: I would recommend the headless option.  The headless install brings with it way fewer dependencies and fewer packages installed on the target system.  This is especially important if storage is at a premium on your target system.

This is true for EL-based Linux servers (RHEL, Oracle, Alma, Rocky, CentOS, etc.).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Java world, “headless” means “with no GUI”, where GUI is understood as a local UI (as opposed to a UI rendered on some remote system using HTML for example). So most server applications work fine with a headless JRE. One side-effect is that headless JREs don’t pull in X11 dependencies.

There are some exceptions; some Java programs don’t have a UI but still need GUI-related modules or packages, *e.g.* for image processing. Those programs end up needing (or used to, I haven’t set one up for a while) a non-headless JRE.

If you’re on Debian, the Tomcat packages depend on a headless JRE by default; that’s a strong indicator that headless JREs are appropriate in most cases.

Answer (score 2):

The *headless* is some weird term (and I hope becoming obsolete) to describe a system without keyboard and screen. For Java, it means it will not have support for GUI interface, which it is a significant part, and also a complex part).

In a server usually you do not need a Java GUI, so a headless version would be enough. Note: it is about Java GUI, and so Java using operating system to display things. It is not about creating or manipulating images, etc.